# 2006 Chevy 2500hd 6.0 gas. Brakes need help!

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, silverado

Ok so I am really lost on this decided to rebuild my front total rebuild and new wheel bearings and hubs and level my truck and get bigger tires well after all of that my brakes would go to the floor when I turn my steering weel all the way (right or left) like when you hang a uie when going straight they work great. so I change my master cylinder and did a brake fluid flush still the same so I change my brake booster (hydro boost) still the same don't know what eles to do brake pads are fine wearing even.  Caliber Are not sticking. Just don't know thank you for any help. Truck has 45000 mil on it and it is. 2 wheel drive.

Comment: Are you missing any brake fluid when this happens? Did you get longer brake lines? I would bet you will find that one of the brake lines is getting pulled taught when you turn full-stop and is causing a leak at the caliper where the banjo bolt attaches. It's the only thing I can think of which would be causing this ... but if you aren't missing any brake fluid, this would not be the case. The problem has to lie at the caliper end, not the master cylinder.

Comment: No I am not  losing any brake fluid I turn my wheels all the way and looked up under their. brake lines have plenty of slack in them none are pulled tight

Comment: If this makes since it almost acks like something is pushing the caliper piston back which is giving me a farther break pedal because if I pump my brakes one or two times my brakes come back to a normal.

Comment: Did you bench bleed the master cylinder before you installed it??

Comment: @mike - Good question. Remember, though, this is only happening when the wheel is at full lock. If there was an issue with a bench bleed, it would be happening all the time, IMHO.

Comment: Yea I did bench bleed the master cylinder there is something in my front end torquing but nothing is Bent because the truck goes straight down the road. And ball joint and tie rods and wheel bearings are new so mabe Aarm bushing or does anyone else have and thought what eles could cause my tire to torque wile turning

Comment: I've been thinking about this all day. I'm wondering, since this is a hydroboost setup, if when you are steering all the way left/right it might be affecting the power output to the brake booster ... I don't know how you'd go about checking it, exactly, but this might be an area to check. I don't know if this would indicate the pump, brake booster, or steering rack, though.

Comment: How I the brake fluid level in the reservoir when the wheels are in full lock? How does it compare to when the wheels are pointing straight?

Comment: Brake fluid is fine

Comment: Just a update for anyone that might ever come across this and say that is my exact problem my shock extender for my level kit were installed backwards which was comeing in contact with the back of my brake caliber during a hard turn flipped them around problem solved. Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the OP's comment to answer the question as there is no way anyone on here could have figured this out without being able to see the issue or having done it themselves:

> Just an update for anyone that might ever come across this and say that is my exact problem my shock extender for my level kit were installed backwards which was coming in contact with the back of my brake caliber during a hard turn flipped them around problem solved.